# PHP User Registration And Login System

Tags: php

I'm a beginner inn PHP and I was wondering how I can create a user registration and login system. Looked on to some tutorials online, and downloaded the source codes but when a user registers, it only shows, "User Successfully Registered!" On the register page and does not redirect the user into the user/login page. Is there any tutorial that anyone knows which shows/teaches this kind of thing? If so, please provide me with a link and if anyone is willing to help me out any other way, please kindly do so.

This is my *dbconroller.php* code:

```
<?php
class DBController {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $database = "registered_users";

    function __construct() {
        $conn = $this->connectDB();
        if(!empty($conn)) {
            $this->selectDB($conn);
        }
    }

    function connectDB() {
        $conn = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
        return $conn;
    }

    function selectDB($conn) {
        mysql_select_db($this->database,$conn);
    }

    function runQuery($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }       
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }

    function numRows($query) {
        $result  = mysql_query($query);
        $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;   
    }

    function updateQuery($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    function insertQuery($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    function deleteQuery($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And this is my *registered_users.sql* code:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.4.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Nov 22, 2014 at 12:48 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.32
-- PHP Version: 5.4.19

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `phppot_examples`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `registered_users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `registered_users` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

And my *index.php* is:

```
<?php
if(count($_POST)>0) {
    /* Form Required Field Validation */
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if(empty($_POST[$key])) {
    $message = ucwords($key) . " field is required";
    break;
    }
    }
    /* Password Matching Validation */
    if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_password']){ 
    $message = 'Passwords should be same<br>'; 
    }

    /* Email Validation */
    if(!isset($message)) {
    if (!filter_var($_POST["userEmail"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $message = "Invalid UserEmail";
    }
    }

    /* Validation to check if gender is selected */
    if(!isset($message)) {
    if(!isset($_POST["gender"])) {
    $message = " Gender field is required";
    }
    }

    /* Validation to check if Terms and Conditions are accepted */
    if(!isset($message)) {
    if(!isset($_POST["terms"])) {
    $message = "Accept Terms and conditions before submit";
    }
    }

    if(!isset($message)) {
        require_once("dbcontroller.php");
        $db_handle = new DBController();
        $query = "INSERT INTO registered_users (user_name, first_name, last_name, password, email, gender) VALUES
        ('" . $_POST["userName"] . "', '" . $_POST["firstName"] . "', '" . $_POST["lastName"] . "', '" . md5($_POST["password"]) . "', '" . $_POST["userEmail"] . "', '" . $_POST["gender"] . "')";
        $result = $db_handle->insertQuery($query);
        if(!empty($result)) {
            $message = "You have been successfully registered!";    
            unset($_POST);
        } else {
            $message = "Problem in registration. Try Again!";   
        }
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP User Registration Form</title>
<style>
.message {color: #FF0000;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;width: 100%;padding: 10;}
body{width:610px;}
.demo-table {background:#FFDFDF;width: 100%;border-spacing: initial;margin: 20px 0px;word-break: break-word;table-layout: auto;line-height:1.8em;color:#333;}
.demo-table td {padding: 20px 15px 10px 15px;}
.demoInputBox {padding: 7px;border: #F0F0F0 1px solid;border-radius: 4px;}
.btnRegister {padding: 10px;background-color: #09F;border: 0;color: #FFF;cursor: pointer;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frmRegistration" method="post" action="">
<table border="0" width="500" align="center" class="demo-table">
<div class="message"><?php if(isset($message)) echo $message; ?></div>
<tr>
<td>Username</td>
<td><input type="text" class="demoInputBox" name="userName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['userName'])) echo $_POST['userName']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td><input type="text" class="demoInputBox" name="firstName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['firstName'])) echo $_POST['firstName']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td><input type="text" class="demoInputBox" name="lastName" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['lastName'])) echo $_POST['lastName']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td><input type="password" class="demoInputBox" name="password" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Confirm Password</td>
<td><input type="password" class="demoInputBox" name="confirm_password" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td><input type="text" class="demoInputBox" name="userEmail" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['userEmail'])) echo $_POST['userEmail']; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gender</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" <?php if(isset($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender']=="Male") { ?>checked<?php  } ?>> Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" <?php if(isset($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender']=="Female") { ?>checked<?php  } ?>> Female
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="terms"> I accept Terms and Conditions</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="btnRegister">
</div>
</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: First off, "providing links" isn't what this forum is about. We'd be happy to help you troubleshoot - if you show us the code you're working on. Can't really help you otherwise. Post the code in your question (formatted properly) and describe the issue.

Comment: If the code built in a tutorial does not meet your needs, you can always modify it. I have [a substantial tutorial here](http://ilovephp.jondh.me.uk/) - it does a lot of user stuff, and by the end of it I expect a keen beginner would be able to have a go at creating a registration form.

Comment: I have updated my question - with the codes provided.